# Delete null values in a column based on a group column

Tags: pyspark, null

I have a dataset that has a group, ID and target column.  I am attempting to eliminate null target values by the Group column, ignoring the ID column. I'd like to do this in PySpark.

```
| Group | ID  | Target   |
| ----- | --- | -------- |
| A     | B   |  10      |
| A     | B   |  10      |
| A     | B   |  10      |
| A     | C   | null     |
| A     | C   | null     |
| A     | C   | null     |
| B     | D   | null     |
| B     | D   | null     |
| B     | D   | null     |
```

This is the resulting dataset I'm looking for:

```
| Group | ID  | Target   |
| ----- | --- | -------- |
| A     | B   |  10      |
| A     | B   |  10      |
| A     | B   |  10      | 
| B     | D   | null     |
| B     | D   | null     |
| B     | D   | null     |
```

In other words, if the group has a target value already, I don't need the values in that group that have a null target, regardless of their ID.  However, I need to make sure every group has a target that is not null, so if there is a group that has only null targets, they cannot be dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute `max(target)` per group and assign this to all rows in the of the group. Then filter rows such that a if maximum is null then select the row is if maximum is not null and target is also not null.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

data = [("A", "B", 10),
 ("A", "B", 10),
 ("A", "B", 10),
 ("A", "C", None),
 ("A", "C", None),
 ("A", "C", None),
 ("B", "D", None),
 ("B", "D", None),
 ("B", "D", None),]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("Group", "ID", "Target",))


window_spec = Window.partitionBy("Group")

df.withColumn("max_target", F.max("Target").over(window_spec))\
  .filter((F.col("max_target").isNull()) | 
          (F.col("Target").isNotNull() & F.col("max_target").isNotNull()))\
  .drop("max_target")\
  .show()
```

### Output

```
+-----+---+------+
|Group| ID|Target|
+-----+---+------+
|    A|  B|    10|
|    A|  B|    10|
|    A|  B|    10|
|    B|  D|  null|
|    B|  D|  null|
|    B|  D|  null|
+-----+---+------+
```

Comment: Yep, that works! Thanks!  Out of curiosity, what if I had multiple values per group in the Target column, and wanted to collect them into an array, but still wanted to eliminate the Nulls?

Comment: You can apply a `collect_list` https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list.html on top of the output, `collect_list` collects only non-null values.